# How to get cortana not to redirect me to the web, but answer it on cortana?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cortana

I just got windows 10, and I'm trying to use cortana. I don't have a mic, so I have to type everything in. When I type in a command, (ex. "Play all albums",) I get an option to search the web, it doesn't actually tell me the answer.

I tried various things like "What's the keyboard shortcut for paste" (I saw that on the web,) but it gives me an option to search it on the web, it doesn't give me the answer on cortana itself. How can I get it to show on cortana itself?

Comment: Are you sure ""Play all albums" is a valid Cortana command?  Cortana on PC is less feature rich then Cortana on Windows Phone.  There are things you can do on the phone that cannot be done on PC or on other mobile platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually doesn't matter, whether you type your question in via keyboard or whether you ask it through your microphone. In both cases it "lands" in the text box, however you have to use the correct syntax. Here is a list of questions for Cortana, which aren't linked to the webbrowser (Adopted from [here](http://bgr.com/2015/08/05/windows-10-cortana-commands-tips-tricks/), you find even more):

> - What’s the weather like?
> - What’s on my schedule?
> - What’s the status of my flight?
> - How long will it take me to get to [place]?
> - Show me directions to [place]
> - Show me my notes
> - Create an appointment
> - Move my appointment
> - Set a reminder
> - Show my reminders
> - Set an alarm
> - Show me my alarms

Of course Cortana speaks in the language you have Windows installed with, so you have to translate them in the case your Windows installation is not English or adding 'English' in the Windows Settings.